# Remove custom taxonomy slug from URL

Tags: custom-taxonomy, permalinks

I'm using custom post type with custom taxonomies for my website and currently my URL is as follows:

`www.website.com/taxonomy_slug/taxonomy_category`

So an example realworld URL would be:

`www.website.com/kernal_category/filmmaking`

- The taxonomy slug is `kernal_category`
- The taxonomy category is `filmmaking`

I want to remove  the taxonomy slug so that the url would more simply read `www.website.com/filmmaking` however none of the changes I have tried work.

My current Permalink settings are set to `wwww.website.com/%category%/` however I have tried changing this to anything else (including /%postname%/)and it seems to have no affect on my website URLs.

Could someone suggest the proper way of fixing this, and also highlight some possible obstacles that may be preventing this from working.

This link did not work for me - [Remove Custom Taxonomy Slug from Permalink](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/46212/remove-custom-taxonomy-slug-from-permalink)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to create a slug of your own. And then link it up to your desire things.

Just use this function:

```
function slugify($str){
$search = array('Ș', 'Ț', 'ş', 'ţ', 'Ş', 'Ţ', 'ș', 'ț', 'î', 'â', 'ă', 'Î', 'Â', 'Ă', 'ë', 'Ë');
$replace = array('s', 't', 's', 't', 's', 't', 's', 't', 'i', 'a', 'a', 'i', 'a', 'a', 'e', 'E');
$str = str_ireplace($search, $replace, strtolower(trim($str)));
$str = preg_replace('/[^\w\d-\ ]/', '', $str);
$str = str_replace(' ', '-', $str);
return (substr($str, -1) == '-' ? substr($str, 0, -1) : $str );
}
```

and provide the string into this function bingo! I did little bit customization in this function.

**What I am saying is create a custom-field with custom-post-type then make it read-only. And put your desire link in there. Everything will be fine.**